# regex in C language to pull chrome version out of user agent

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to write a C code with regex.h library  that can find out a Chrome version from user agent. I am trying below

```
regex_t re;
regmatch_t pm;

if(regcomp(&re, "Chrom[^ \\/]+\\/(\\d+)[\\.\\d]* ", 0) != 0) {
    cout << "C - Invalid Regex\n";
    return;
} else {
    cout << "C - valid Regex\n";
}

if ( regexec(&re, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.3987.66 Safari/537.36", 1, &pm, 0) == 0 ) {
    cout << "Match Found !!" << "start location: " << pm.rm_so << "end location: " << pm.rm_eo << "\n";
} else {
    cout << "Match Not Found\n";
}
regfree(&re);
```

but this does not work and it prints "Match Not Found". What am i missing ?

Comment: What is `Cpp language`? Why did you tag this with both "c" and "c++" despite the description of those tags?

Comment: For starters, your regex should have `Chrome` instead of `Chrom`. That said, regex is used for extracting data which follows a certain pattern. If you do not specify the format in which the chrome version exists, it will be difficult for anyone to answer your question. Give some sample inputs and output, and please mention the format of the version i.e. does it have letters in it, will there be spaces in between etc.

Comment: cout << etc is not C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
regcomp(&re, "Chrome\\/[0-9]+[.[0-9]+]*", REG_EXTENDED)
```

You can get more info about regex.h here:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regex.h.html